# How to add space before a particular string in python

Tags: python, for-loop, cjk

I have the following output after removing all spaces from a string

```
テレビを付けて

テレビつけて

つけて

テレビをオンにして
```

However, I'm trying to add a space either after the を character, or before つけて after テレビ

The desired output is as follows

```
テレビを 付けて

テレビ つけて

つけて

テレビを オンにして
```

I've tried to use some def function but not sure how to finish it off, or even if it'll work.

```
def teform(txt):

    if x = "オンにして":
        return " して"
    elif y = "つけて":
        return " つけて"
    elif z = "付けて":
        return " 付けて"
    else: 
        return  # ...(not sure what goes here)
```

Comment: `x = stuff` *assigns*, it does not *compare*. Use `==` instead.

Comment: What are `x`, `y`, and `z`? Did you want to compare `txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `=` to compare items, you must use `==`.

Apart from the wrong comparing syntax, it seems you don't really know how to approach this – you don't need a loop of any kind. Just use [`txt.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace) to target and change those specific substrings:

```
def teform(txt):
    # add a space after を
    txt = txt.replace ('を','を ')
    # add a space between テレビ and つけて
    txt = txt.replace ('テレビつけて', 'テレビ つけて')
    return txt
```

Comment: thanks! yeah im still a noob at this, but this is what i was looking for (: